# Bullets and Numbering output in tinymce

Tags: tinymce, libreoffice

I'm using the tinymce editor, and I wondering if there is a way of reproducing this behaviour, or a plugin that will allow me to do this:

[Libre office numbering output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pf3c.png)

Currently if I try anything with the advlist plugin this happens:

[tinymce numbering output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omWl9.png)

Maybe I can implement the libre office code in the tinymce, but I cannot find the numbering and bullets chunks of code.

Comment: Can't you just do a `Ctrl`+`Enter`?

Comment: No, that only seems to work on word and open office. In the advlist plugin the count starts once an element is not part of the list and its not even alligned with the other members of the list

Comment: For the code, LibreOffice uses paragraph styles to set numbering and bullets.  Andrew Pitonyak's paper "English Macro Document" (available as a free download from http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) has a section titled "Outline Numbering" with some example code.